# No changes done by static function in HTML in Django

Tags: python, django

Html File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is from index.html</h1>
{{help_me}}
<img src="{% static "images/DjangoGuitar.jpg" %}" alt="sorry text not loaded">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS file

```
h1{
    color: red;
}
```

Output:
This is from index.html
Welcome to the page sorry text not loaded

Comment: Is the css/style.css is inside the /static folder right?.

Comment: Yes, It is inside static folder.

Comment: ```STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')```                                 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    STATIC_DIR
]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enclosing the `css/style.css` part in single quotes to see if it works? Like so `<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`.

The double quotes at `"css/style` mean you have closed the first one beginning at `href="{%`

Comment: Likely the issue. `href=""` is conflicting with the inner `"css/style.css"` in OP's current code.

Comment: still there is no change in the text to color red